# VHDL optimization tips

Tags: optimization, vhdl

I am quite new in VHDL, and by using different IP cores (by different providers) can see that sometimes they differ massively as per the space that they occupy or timing constraints.

I was wondering if there are rules of thumb for optimization in VHDL (like there are in C, for example; unroll your loops, etc.).

Is it related to the synthesis tools I am using (like the different compilers are using other methods of optimization in C, so you need to learn to read the feedback asm files they return), or is it dependent on my coding skills?

Answer (score 6):

> Is it related to the synthesis tools I am using (like the different compilers are using other methods of optimization in C, so you need to learn to read the feedback asm files they return), or is it dependent on my coding skills?

The answer is "yes." When you are coding in HDL, you are actually describing hardware (go figure).  Instead of the code being converted into machine code (like it would with C) it is synthesized to logical functions (AND, NOT, OR, XOR, etc) and memory elements (RAM, ROM, FF...).

VHDL can be used in many different ways. You can use VHDL in a purely **structural** sense where at the base level you are calling our primitives of the underlying technology that you are targeting. For example, you literally instantiate every AND, OR, NOT, and Flip Flop in your design.  While this can give you a lot of control, it is not an efficient use of time in 99% of cases.

You can also implement hardware using **behavioral** constructs with VHDL. Instead of explicitly calling out each logic element, you describe a function to be implemented. For example, *if this, do this, otherwise, do something else*. You can describe state machines, math operations, and memories all in a behavioral sense. There are huge advantages to describing hardware in a behavioral sense:

1. Easier for humans to understand
2. Easier for humans to maintain
3. More portable between synthesis tools and target hardware

When using behavioral constructs, knowing your synthesis tool *and* your target hardware can help in understanding how what you write will actually be implemented. For example, if you describe a memory element with a asynchronous reset the implementation in hardware will be different for architectures with a dedicated asynchronous reset input to the memory element and one without.

Synthesis tools will generally publish in their reference manual or user guide a list of suggested HDL constructs to use in order to obtain some desired implementation result. For basic cases, they will be what you would expect. For more elaborate behavior models (e.g. a dual port RAM) there may be some form that you need to follow for the tool to "recognize" what you are describing.

In summary, for best use of your target device:

1. Know the device you are targeting. How are the programmable elements laid out? How many inputs and outputs are there from lookup tables? Read the device user manual to find out.
2. Know your synthesis engine. What types of behavioral constructs will be recognized and how will they be implemented? Read the synthesis tool user guide or reference manual to find out. Additionally, experiment by synthesizing small constructs to see how it gets implemented (via RTL or technology viewer, if available).
3. Know VHDL. Understand the differences between signals and variables. Be able to recognize statements that will generate many levels of logic in your design.

> I was wondering if there are rules of thumb for optimization in VHDL

Now that you know the hardware, synthesis tool, and VHDL... Assuming you want to design for maximum performance, the following concepts should be adhered to:

- **Pipeline, pipeline, pipeline**.  The more levels of logic you have between synchronous elements, the more difficulty you are going to have making your timing constraint/goal.
- **Pipeline some more.** Having additional stages of registers can provide additional wiggle-room in the future if you need to add more processing steps to your algorithm without affecting the overall latency/timeline.
- **Be careful when operating on the boundaries of the normal fabric.** For example, if interfacing with an IO pin, dedicated multiplies, or other special hardware, you will take more significant timing hits. Additional memory elements should be placed here to avoid critical paths forming.
- **Review your synthesis and implementation reports frequently.** You can learn a lot from reviewing these frequently. For example, if you add a new feature, and your timing takes a hit, you just introduced a critical path. Why? How can you alleviate this issue?
- **Take care with your "global" structures -- such as resets.** Logic that must be widely distributed in your design deserves special care, since it needs to reach across your whole device. You may need special pipeline stages, or timing constraints on this type of logic. If at all possible, avoid "global" structures, unless truly a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

While synthesis tools have design goals to focus on area, speed or power, the designer's choices and skills is the major contributor for the quality of the output. A designer should have a goal to maximize speed or minimize area and it will greatly influence his choices. A design optimized for speed can be made smaller by asking the tool to reduce the area, but not nearly as much as the same design thought for area in the first place.

However, it is more complicated than that. IP cores often target several FPGA technologies as well as ASIC. This can only be achieved by using general VHDL constructs, (or re-writing the code for each target, which non-critical IP providers don't do). FPGA and ASIC vendor have primitives that will improve speed/area when used, but if you write code to use a primitive for a technology, it doesn't mean that the resulting code will be optimized if you change the technology. Both Xilinx and Altera have DSP blocks to speed multiplication and whatnot, but they don't work exactly the same and writing code that uses the full potential of both is very challenging.

Synthesis tools are notorious for doing exactly what you ask them to, even if a more optimized solution is simple, for example:

```
a <= (x + y) + z; -- This is a 2 cascaded 2-input adder
b <= x + y + z; -- This is a 3-input adder
```

Will likely lead a different path from xyz to b/c. In the end, the designer need to know what he wants, and he has to verify that the synthesis tool understands his intent.